# CKEditor font-size drop-down does not appear sometimes

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I am using inline CKEditor in my website. Sometimes the CKEditor works fine, but sometimes the font-size drop-down does not appear on click of the select box. After refreshing the page 2-3 times, the drop-down appears.

The editors are added after page load through ajax and sometimes there can be multiple editors.

Can anyone please tell me why this issue occurs and how can I fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Comment: It might not loading properly.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: are you using any third party js for ckeditor or fonts ? your website is slow, put your all js in footer, and css in header.

Comment: All resources are loaded from local setup. No external resources are loaded. Website is quite fast.

Comment: css are always put in the header and we have only few js files.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

That sometimes happens when, the CKEditor is replaced with same element more than once. Try to destroy the editor while reloading for same element, using `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy();`, where `editor1` is your current editor.

For more info see [destroy](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#destroy)

**Update**

and if you have multiple CK Editor instances you can destroy them by:

```
 for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].destroy();
                    }
```